.net 6 app throwing error An error occurred while loading required library libhostpolicy.so after patching update
I have a .net 6 app deployed on a Linux server which already have .net 6 installed.
The server was patched recently and after that my service stopped working. I tried enable/start/restart but It won't work and looking at the journalctl result I can see this
error
An error occurred while loading required library libhostpolicy.so from [/var/www/Myservice/]
Failed to load /var/www/MyService/libhostpolicy.so, error: /var/www/MyService/libhostpolicy.so: failed to map segment
I can see the file libhostpolicy.so and same premissions are assigned to it as the rest of the files.
